# change datepattern (timestamp) position inside log filename

Tags: java, log4j

In log4j there is the possibility to set a timestamp for the DailyRollingFileAppender so i've set it in this way :

```
log4j.appender.A1.File=aleroot.log
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern='-'ddMMyyyy
```

and the generated rotation log file name is like the following :

```
aleroot.log-28112011
```

i want to change the format of the log filename in this way :

```
aleroot-28112011.log
```

How can i change the pattern to generate a log with the desired file name ?  Is it possible ?

Furthermore the current log file name generated is aleroot.log without the the timestamp, can i force log4j to generate the filename with the timestamp also for the current log ? How can it be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a perfect solution [TimestampFileAppender](http://markmail.org/message/5on2bmatywehnbn7) .

Example configuration :

```
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.TimestampFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.TimestampPattern=ddMMyyyy
log4j.appender.A1.File=aleroot-{timestamp}.log
```